# Using UIActivityViewController to share a video

Tags: ios, video, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to use the default apple share screen to share a video to things like twitter and facebook. I have got this to work with an image but I do not know how change this to work with a video. Thanks in advance!

Here is the code I am using to share the photo:

```
(IBAction)shareButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    UIImage *imagetoshare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"First_Time_Travel"];
    NSArray *activityItems = @[imagetoshare];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You need a file URL to the video file or and `ALAsset` representing the video. Use either of those as the object in your `activityItems` array.

Answer (score 4):

> For swift 3.0 OR up

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "URL String Here")
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = controller.view // so that iPads won't crash
controller.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an avasset, you can get the url using (AVUrlAsset*)AVAsset.url