# Email option is not available while sharing video using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Hi I am trying to share video using UIActivityViewController but it is not showing Email option. It is showing Facebook and Message option. But in native Photos app it is showing Email share option on same video. So please could anyone tell me why it is not showing Email option in my App. Here is my code:

```
  NSURL* url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"asset url here"];

  [self shareItems:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:url,nil]]; 

- (IBAction)shareItems:(NSMutableArray*)shareItems {


    UIActivityViewController *shareController =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
     // actual items are prepared by UIActivityItemSource protocol methods below
     initWithActivityItems: shareItems
     applicationActivities :nil];


    [self presentViewController: shareController animated: YES completion: nil];

}
```

The same code is working fine (Shows Email option) if Asset Url is of an image. Problem is in case of Video. I have tried on iPhone5 with iOS7.

Comment: Please refer following link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992842/using-uiactivityviewcontroller-to-share-a-video

Comment: No that link is not working